# winterba.sh redirects to 2012 Winter Bash

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013

Visiting http://winterba.sh/ redirects to [the 2012 Winter Bash](https://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash).

This domain should be reused, and should redirect to [the current year's Winter Bash](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/).

Why did I think this would happen? The use of this domain was announced in the original email to moderators, which read in relevant part:

> This event will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Comment: This is by design. http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1679630#1679630

Comment: Did they mention winterba.sh on any notices for Winterborsch 2013?

Comment: @random `Winterborsch`? Is this some new "special" hat you speak of?

Comment: It is borshch, please. Better still, борщ. Can't you see Anna is reading this?

Comment: @ЯegDwight Thanks, I appreciate it. Although now I'm hungry for some борщ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The email went out to moderators before we decided to use [the current URL](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com). This was decided because it would be a huge technical pain to reuse winterba.sh after redirecting it to stackexchange.com/promos, and it is not a precedent we wanted to set.

In short: winterba.sh will continue to redirect to promos, and all links that are purporting to be about this year's promo should be changed to the current URL.

But since this mixup is our fault, that's what I'll be spending my morning on tomorrow. :)

**Update**: I have gone through and changed all the links in child metas that [come up in Ilmari's Google search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211962/winterba-sh-redirects-to-2012-winter-bash/211970#comment681694_211964). If you stumble across more and can't edit them, ping me here and I will fix them.

Comment: More technically, it's a 301 (permanent) redirect, which means browsers cache it *forever*. There's no way to fix that without a bunch of people getting to the wrong place.

Comment: @DavidFullerton In theory that's true. In practice, well, [browser caches are not infinite](http://serverfault.com/q/451348/126632).

Comment: [Found one more.](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/566/do-we-want-hats-winter-bash-event) Er, [two more](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/496/the-stackexchange-winter-bash-is-on-again-for-2013-everyone-keen).

Comment: @Ilmari Done and done.

Comment: That was fast. :) While you're at it, you might want to fix the comment on the second one too.

Comment: @Ilmari And done!

Comment: [Here's a few more](http://www.google.com/search?q=winterba.sh+inurl:meta+inurl:stackexchange.com+daterange:2456444-2456657) just to make your Christmas Eve even more fun. ;) (Now with 90% less false positives! And wow, figuring out how to properly link to that search was seriously non-trivial.) (Edit: Oops, also with 90% less real positives, I see. [Here's the original link again.](http://www.google.com/search?q=winterba.sh+inurl:meta+inurl:stackexchange.com+2013))

Comment: Pretty sure I got 'em all before you de-last-year'd the search query. Let me know if you find any others.

Comment: Currently you create a sub domain of stackexchange, e.g, `winterbash2016.stackexchange.com` Couldn't you create  a sub domain of winterba.sh instead?

Comment: @MartinSmith that would be pointless, the whole point of winterba.sh is being as short as possible, adding sub domain to it will defeat its very purpose. winterbash2016.stackexchange.com is longer, but crystal clear what it is exactly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard `http://2016.winterba.sh` seems OK to me.

Comment: @Martin well, probably same technical difficulty anyway, David might know more about it, you should be able to ping him as well.

Answer (score 4):

http://winterba.sh was the site for Winter Bash 2012. We opted not to bring it back for this year and instead to leave it pointing at the original event's archive.

None of the posts announcing this year's event used that URL (and if they did - *that* is a bug :)), so it's best if we just let it rest in peace at this point.

Comment: *cough* Apparently you people used it in the first email. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11706/math-se-and-winter-bash-2013

Comment: @hichris123 Those responsible will be sacked.

Comment: Yep, I went back through my old emails; it was definitely used in the announcement to moderators.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Yeah, looks like [we might have a problem here](https://www.google.com/search?q="16+december+2013"+"will+be+able+to+see+their+entire+hat+collection+on+http%3A%2F%2Fwinterba.sh"&filter=0).